# thread_local + std::thread deadlock on destruction

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, msvcrt, compiler-bug

Anyone knows what kind of UB is this? The following code deadlocks on `jthread` destruction when built with MSVC 19.29.30148, sometimes it deadlocks after std::cout and sometimes before.
This is somehow related to thread_local, but I cannot see what is the issue. It seems to work fine under other compilers and platforms.

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::thread t2(
        [&] {
            thread_local std::jthread asd([] {
                    std::cout << "ASD" << std::endl;
                    });
        });
    if (t2.joinable()) { t2.join(); }
}
```

Update: Reproducible both on static and dynamic runtime

Comment: Looks like a C++ library bug to me.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, yep, to me too. It seems the issue is in "join" operation called during thread_local destruction (even through many layers of indirection). It is somehow causes issues in MS runtime, but I am not sure if they mentioned/documented it anywhere.

Comment: There is reported bug: [thread_local Type Containing std::thread Never Finishes Execution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/thread_local-Type-Containing-std::thread/10409436). Looks the same issue.